# LARAVEL 5.2 Routing Object Not Found

Tags: php, apache, routes, laravel-5

i usually use development laravel with artisan, but in this case i must set laravel in lampp. i have route like

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors', 'prefix' => 'service'], function () {

  Route::group(['prefix' => 'master'], function () {

    Route::resource('produk', 'Master\ProdukController');
    Route::resource('agama', 'Master\AgamaController');
  });
Route::resource('list-generic', 'ListGeneric', ['only' => ['index']]);
});
```

and my .htacess in public folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

my problem is. when i access this link:

```
http://172.16.16.1/a-web/service/list-generic?select=id
```

it perfectly work, 
but when i access with this link with "/" after list-generic:

```
http://172.16.16.1/a-web/service/list-generic/?select=id
```

show error object not found, 
please need help..

Comment: What is the exact error you are receiving?

Answer (score 1):

This must be because of your route file. 
When you add
 `Route::resource('list-generic', 'ListGeneric', ['only' => ['index']]);`
Laravel will only use the route

```
http://172.16.16.1/a-web/service/list-generic
```

and Not

```
http://172.16.16.1/a-web/service/list-generic/
```

for the above route  to work you will have to add the optional parameter to the `route`

```
Route::resource('list-generic/{?query}', 'ListGeneric', ['only' => ['index']]);
```

This route will handle all both type of links.

Comment: what make me confused is, why in nginx is work perfectly, 
i have found solution for apache server, i must use .httpaccess like comment post below, 
anyway, thanks for your answers :)

Comment: Nope, this is not correct, it means the query parameter is optional

Comment: The issue is using different query styles

Comment: @Mina Abadir this means my answer is wrong ? I mean even if I don't use optional parameter both the route i.e. with and without `/` should work. Right ?

Comment: While working on my project I had observed this behavior and my answer was based on that. Please let me know your comment so that I can update or remove my answer on it's basis.

Answer (score 1):

i have found solution for my own question. 
finally i must edit .httaccess file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /a-web/

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```